# duplicate rows in table, but need to change data in one column

Tags: sql

I have the table **step_year**: id, step_id, year

I want to duplicate all rows that have year = 1011 (select * from step_year where year = 1011), but instead of those newly created rows having the same year (1011) I want to change it to 1112.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: When you say "duplicate", are you re-inserting the records, or merely selecting double the records?

Comment: copying the rows as new rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the `INSERT` based on a `SELECT` but specify the year instead of pulling it from the query

```
INSERT INTO `step_year` (`id`, `step_id`, `year`)
SELECT `id`, `step_id`, 1112 AS `year` 
FROM `step_year` where `year` = 1011
```

This syntax is for MySQL, but should be adaptable to most databases.

Answer (score 1):

If your database supports it:

```
INSERT INTO step_year
(id, step_id, year)
SELECT sub_year.id, sub_year.step_id, 1112
  FROM step_year sub_year
  WHERE sub_year.year = 1011
```

Comment: you need to leave out `VALUES` for this syntax, and you don't need to alias `step_year` unless you want to.

Answer (score 1):

```
insert into step_year(id, step_id,year)
select id,step_id,1112 from step_year where year = 1011
```

Answer (score 1):

If id field is auto incremental, use this

```
INSERT INTO step_year(step_id,year)
           SELECT step_id, 1112 FROM step_year WHERE year = 1011
```

if id field is not auto incremental

```
INSERT INTO step_year(id, step_id, year)
           SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY id) + COUNT(year) id, step_id, 1112 FROM step_year WHERE year = 1011
```